# Will you now have three hours?

Tags: phrase-meaning, future-constructions

Two persons A and B have known each other for a while. A is interested in B's life. One day, A gets up the courage to ask B a question.

> A: Can you tell me about your life?

> B: **You got three hours?**

> A: Yes, I do.

---

I can't change the boldfaced sentence to the following:

> B: *Will you have three hours?*

This is wrong.

But if I add the word "now"? Does it work?

> B: **Will you *now* have three hours?**

> A: Yes.

Comment: Why do you think adding "now" makes the bad grammar good?

Comment: B's question means "Have you got/Do you have three hours?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will you have three hours?

is not wrong, it just needs a context set up in the future. For example,

> When you are done with this... Whenever that will be... Will you have 3 hours for me [then]?

Adding *now* to this sentence makes it semantically incorrect. You simply can't use *now* **in the future**.

> -I am fixing my car.
> -How much time do you need?
> -20 minutes.
> <strike>-Will you have 3 hours now?</strike>  *(it doesn't make sense)*
> -Will you have 3 hours then?

However, you can use *now* if the context is set up **at the present time**.

> We will now rise and sing the National Anthem. *(from your comment)*
> And now I will perform a magic trick!

[In stories and accounts of past events, now is used to refer to the particular time that is being written or spoken about.](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/now)